# Angular array data binding

Tags: angular

I haven't understood why this code always prints only the first element of the array repeat two times ("AAA","AAA")
Am I missing something ? Maybe I am using bad the data binding.

TS:

```
var x ="AAAA,BBBB";
this.items = x.split(',');
```

HTML:

```
<div   *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">    
         <input [(ngModel)]="model.arrayListVariables [i]"  name="variable{{i}}" formControlName="variable" class="form-control" type="text">     
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzlzea

thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine. Not sure, why it isn't working. Can you create a replica on stackblitz? One suggestion, instead of `[(ngModle)]="model.arrayListVariables [i]"` try to use `[(ngModle)]="item"`.

Comment: you can have a look to this stackblitz : stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzlzea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzlzea), I found below issue.

You are using the same `formControlName` for both the inputs, i.e. `variable`. You need to use different names for different inputs.

So, I would suggest you make changes like below :

**app.component.html**

```html
...
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item"  name="variable{{i}}" [formControlName]="'variable'+i" type="text">
</div>
...
```

**app.component.ts**

```
...
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({                                 
                  variable0: [''],
                  variable1: ['']
      });
...
```

I would also suggest not to use Template Driven and Reactive approach together in form. You can find out more at [Introduction to forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#introduction-to-forms-in-angular).

Comment: thank you so much i have to change something  then :-)